# Deleted files and folders to boot to Ubuntu - any way to retrieve files?

Tags: boot, wubi, data-recovery

I was cleaning up my E: drive, on which I downloaded Ubuntu (using Wubi), and I accidentally deleted the Ubuntu folder, and I also deleted some other files on my E: drive that I didn't recognize. The result of my action is that selecting to boot to Ubuntu results in the following message:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. Choose your language settings, and the click "Next".
3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.  

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr  
Status: 0xc0000098  
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

I read somewhere that the wubildr.mbr file may have been on the E: drive as well, rather than in the Ubuntu folder, as the above message suggests. I deleted every file that I didn't recognize that wasn't in a folder on my E: drive. So it's definitely gone, regardless. I also emptied the recycle bin.

So, here's the thing. I have some files that I saved to the Ubuntu desktop. And I very much need them back. Is there any way I can get them back? I am really hoping that it might be as simple as "Click here to download the folder and files you foolishly deleted and simply place them on your E: drive". I understand that that is unlikely.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Or is it simply a loss that I'm going to have to accept?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I was going to post this as comments, but seeing as it was going to be a series of long comments, and actually have some information in them, I decided to post this answer. I don't like posting answers that don't actually contain clear steps on how to solve an issue, but "data recovery" is not something that can easily be explained over the internet in a post like this; you'll need to do some reading of your own and explore the various tools.</sub>

> "*So it's definitely gone, regardless. I also emptied the recycle bin.*"

Trust me, nothing is gone when you "empty the recycle bin" or Shift+Delete something; it's there, you just don't see it. Not to give you false hope though, because if you want any chance of completely recovering the stuff you deleted, **stop using the computer now!** Or at least, don't copy anything to and from the E partition. The more you use the E partition, the more your deleted folders are actually deleted.

You will need to try data recovery tools to recover your folder/files. There are [several data recovery tools and guides for Windows on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=recover+deleted+files+windows) that you can follow to retrieve the Ubuntu folder and the other files you deleted from your partition.

Unfortunately, even though these "data recovery" tools **do** actually recover data, if you've already used the E drive a bit, you *(and this is my speculation, but you)* might not be able to fully recover the Ubuntu folder the way it was, so you might not be able to normally boot back into your Ubuntu as if nothing happened. I'm unfamiliar with what exactly is in the Ubuntu folder, so I'm not sure if you can somehow, from Windows, read the files inside the Ubuntu folder and be able to browse what was inside your Ubuntu installation without actually having to boot into it.

> *I am really hoping that it might be as simple as "Click here to download the folder and files you foolishly deleted and simply place them on your E: drive."*

Yeaaaah...ehem...about that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alaa! I tried a data recovery tool, and many files popped up, but I didn't see any folders (so no Ubuntu folder), and I didn't see the wubildr file.